# Obtain a div from a webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

I have this code:

```
<?php 


$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://es.flightaware.com/live/findflight/LEMD/KLAX')); 

$belement = $dom->getElementById("ffinder-main");
echo $belement->nodeValue;
?>
```

I'm getting code from http://es.flightaware.com/live/findflight/LEMD/KLAX y I only want to see the div with the id `ffinder-main`. With this code I gets the div but without css so It looks like this:

```
LÃ­nea aÃ©rea Ident Aeronave Estado Salida â–º Llegada ConnectionIberia - Lineas Aerâ€¦ IBE6171 A343 En Vuelo / A Tiempo miÃ©Â 12:45PMÂ CESTMAD â–º LAX04:30PMÂ PDT miÃ©Iberia - Lineas Aerâ€¦ IBE6171 A343 Aterrizado lunÂ 12:45PMÂ CESTMAD â–º LAX04:30PMÂ PDT lunIberia - Lineas Aerâ€¦ IBE6171 A342 Aterrizado vieÂ 12:45PMÂ CESTMAD â–º LAX04:30PMÂ PDT vieSwiss SWR2021 A320 Programado jueÂ 09:35AMÂ CESTMAD â–º ZRHZurich SWR40 A343 Programado ZRH â–º LAX03:49PMÂ PDT jue1 hora 30 minutosAmericana de Aviaciâ€¦ ANE8052 CRK Programado jueÂ 09:05AMÂ CESTMAD â–º DUSDusseldorfAir Berlin BER7430 A332 Programado DUS â–º LAX03:10PMÂ PDT jue1 hora 55 minutosIberia - Lineas Aerâ€¦ IBE3162 A321 Programado jueÂ 08:50AMÂ CESTMAD â–º LHRLondon, EnglandAmerican Airlines AAL137 B77W Programado LHR â–º LAX05:15PMÂ PDT jue3 horas 50 minutosIberia - Lineas Aerâ€¦ IBE3162 A321 Programado jueÂ 08:50AMÂ CESTMAD â–º LHRLondon, EnglandBritish Airways BAW283 B744 Programado LHR â–º LAX03:10PMÂ PDT jue1 hora 55 minutosAir France AFR1401 A319 Programado jueÂ 07:10AMÂ CESTMAD â–º CDGParis AFR66 A388 Programado CDG â–º LAX12:22PMÂ PDT jue1 hora 15 minutosIberia - Lineas Aerâ€¦ IBE3170 A321 Programado jueÂ 06:45AMÂ CESTMAD â–º LHRLondon, EnglandBritish Airways BAW279 B744 Programado LHR â–º LAX12:55PMÂ PDT jue1 hora 20 minutosIberia - Lineas Aerâ€¦ IBE3170 A321 Programado jueÂ 06:45AMÂ CESTMAD â–º LHRLondon, EnglandBritish Airways BAW283 B744 Programado LHR â–º LAX03:10PMÂ PDT jue3 horas 45 minutosLufthansa DLH1121 A321 Programado jueÂ 06:10AMÂ CESTMAD â–º FRAFrankfurt am Main DLH456 B748 Programado FRA â–º LAX12:35PMÂ PDT jue1 hora 30 minutosKLM KLM1708 B738 Programado jueÂ 06:00AMÂ CESTMAD â–º AMSAmsterdam KLM601 B744 Programado AMS â–º LAX11:15AMÂ PDT jue1 hora 15 minutosIberia - Lineas Aerâ€¦ IBE6405 A346 Programado jueÂ 12:40AMÂ CESTMAD â–º MEXMexico CityAlaska Airlines ASA225 B738 Programado MEX â–º LAX09:30AMÂ PDT jue2 horas Air Europa AEA91 A332 En Vuelo / A Tiempo miÃ©Â 05:30PMÂ CESTMAD â–º JFKNew York, NYDelta DAL427 B763 Programado JFK â–º LAX12:20AMÂ PDT jue1 hora 16 minutosIberia - Lineas Aerâ€¦ IBE6117 A333 En Vuelo / A Tiempo miÃ©Â 04:55PMÂ CESTMAD â–º MIAMiami, FLAmerican Airlines AAL2486 B752 Programado MIA â–º LAX11:40PMÂ PDT miÃ©37 minutosIberia - Lineas Aerâ€¦ IBE6253 A342 En Vuelo / A Tiempo miÃ©Â 04:50PMÂ CESTMAD â–º JFKNew York, NYAmerican Airlines AAL185 B762 Programado JFK â–º LAX12:40AMÂ PDT jue2 horas 35 minutosAerovias de Mexico â€¦ AMX2 B772 En Vuelo / A Tiempo miÃ©Â 02:40PMÂ CESTMAD â–º MEXMexico City AMX468 B738 Programado MEX â–º LAX11:35PMÂ PDT miÃ©1 hora 38 minutosBritish Airways BAW459 A319 Cancelado miÃ©Â 02:20PMÂ CESTMAD â–º LHRLondon, England BAW269 B744 En Vuelo / A Tiempo LHR â–º LAX07:15PMÂ PDT miÃ©40 minutosIberia - Lineas Aerâ€¦ IBE3176 A321 resultado desconocido miÃ©Â 01:35PMÂ CESTMAD â–º LHRLondon, EnglandBritish Airways BAW269 B744 En Vuelo / A Tiempo LHR â–º LAX07:15PMÂ PDT miÃ©1 hora American Airlines AAL37 B763 En Vuelo / A Tiempo miÃ©Â 01:00PMÂ CESTMAD â–º DFWDallas-Fort Worth, TX AAL2489 B752 Programado DFW â–º LAX08:25PMÂ PDT miÃ©1 hora 50 minutosAmerican Airlines AAL37 B763 En Vuelo / A Tiempo miÃ©Â 01:00PMÂ CESTMAD â–º DFWDallas-Fort Worth, TX AAL2467 B738 Programado DFW â–º LAX07:00PMÂ PDT miÃ©30 minutosAmerican Airlines AAL37 B763 En Vuelo / A Tiempo miÃ©Â 01:00PMÂ CESTMAD â–º DFWDallas-Fort Worth, TX AAL2477 B752 Programado DFW â–º LAX07:40PMÂ PDT miÃ©1 hora 10 minutosAmerican Airlines AAL37 B763 En Vuelo / A Tiempo miÃ©Â 01:00PMÂ CESTMAD â–º DFWDallas-Fort Worth, TX AAL2495 B738 Programado DFW â–º LAX09:30PMÂ PDT miÃ©3 horas Iberia - Lineas Aerâ€¦ IBE3164 A321 Aterrizado miÃ©Â 12:40PMÂ CESTMAD â–º LHRLondon, EnglandBritish Airways BAW269 B744 En Vuelo / A Tiempo LHR â–º LAX07:15PMÂ PDT miÃ©2 horas 10 minutosUS Airways AWE741 A333 Aterrizado miÃ©Â 12:30PMÂ CESTMAD â–º PHLPhiladelphia, PA AWE701 A321 Programado PHL â–º LAX07:00PMÂ PDT miÃ©1 hora US Airways AWE741 A333 Aterrizado miÃ©Â 12:30PMÂ CESTMAD â–º PHLPhiladelphia, PA AWE717 A321 Programado PHL â–º LAX08:53PMÂ PDT miÃ©2 horas 54 minutosIberia - Lineas Aerâ€¦ IBE6251 A333 Aterrizado miÃ©Â 12:20PMÂ CESTMAD â–º JFKNew York, NYAmerican Airlines AAL133 B762 Carreteando / SaliÃ³ de la puerta de embarque JFK â–º LAX06:40PMÂ PDT miÃ©50 minutosIberia - Lineas Aerâ€¦ IBE6251 A333 Aterrizado miÃ©Â 12:20PMÂ CESTMAD â–º JFKNew York, NYAmerican Airlines AAL181 B762 Programado JFK â–º LAX07:40PMÂ PDT miÃ©1 hora 55 minutosLufthansa DLH1801 A320 Aterrizado miÃ©Â 12:10PMÂ CESTMAD â–º MUCMunich DLH452 A346 En Vuelo / A Tiempo MUC â–º LAX07:15PMÂ PDT miÃ©1 hora 10 minutosIberia - Lineas Aerâ€¦ IBE6361 A343 En Vuelo / A Tiempo miÃ©Â 12:10PMÂ CESTMAD â–º PTYPanama CityCopa Airlines CMP302 B738 Programado PTY â–º LAX10:41PMÂ PDT miÃ©2 horas 44 minutosIberia - Lineas Aerâ€¦ IBE6123 En Vuelo / A Tiempo miÃ©Â 11:50AMÂ CESTMAD â–º MIAMiami, FLAmerican Airlines AAL2415 B738 Programado MIA â–º LAX10:05PMÂ PDT miÃ©3 horas 49 minutosIberia - Lineas Aerâ€¦ IBE6123 En Vuelo / A Tiempo miÃ©Â 11:50AMÂ CESTMAD â–º MIAMiami, FLAmerican Airlines AAL231 B752 Programado MIA â–º LAX08:35PMÂ PDT miÃ©2 horas 29 minutosIberia - Lineas Aerâ€¦ IBE6123 A333 En Vuelo / A Tiempo miÃ©Â 11:50AMÂ CESTMAD â–º MIAMiami, FLAmerican Airlines AAL231 B752 Programado MIA â–º LAX08:35PMÂ PDT miÃ©2 horas 45 minutosIberia - Lineas Aerâ€¦ IBE6275 A346 Aterrizado miÃ©Â 11:45AMÂ CESTMAD â–º ORDChicago, ILAmerican Airlines AAL2271 B738 Programado ORD â–º LAX07:15PMÂ PDT miÃ©2 horas 50 minutosIberia - Lineas Aerâ€¦ IBE6275 A346 Aterrizado miÃ©Â 11:45AMÂ CESTMAD â–º ORDChicago, ILAmerican Airlines AAL1445 B738 Programado ORD â–º LAX06:10PMÂ PDT miÃ©1 hora 50 minutosIberia - Lineas Aerâ€¦ IBE6275 A346 Aterrizado miÃ©Â 11:45AMÂ CESTMAD â–º ORDChicago, ILAmerican Airlines AAL1305 B738 Programado ORD â–º LAX04:55PMÂ PDT miÃ©30 minutosUnited UAL63 B752 Aterrizado miÃ©Â 11:35AMÂ CESTMAD â–º EWRNewark, NJ UAL1455 B738 Programado EWR â–º LAX09:17PMÂ PDT miÃ©3 horas 33 minutosUnited UAL63 B752 Aterrizado miÃ©Â 11:35AMÂ CESTMAD â–º EWRNewark, NJ UAL1554 B752 Programado EWR â–º LAX06:19PMÂ PDT miÃ©51 minutosUnited UAL63 B752 Aterrizado miÃ©Â 11:35AMÂ CESTMAD â–º EWRNewark, NJ UAL6554 B752 Programado EWR â–º LAX06:11PMÂ PDT miÃ©51 minutosUnited UAL63 B752 Aterrizado miÃ©Â 11:35AMÂ CESTMAD â–º EWRNewark, NJ UAL996 B752 Programado EWR â–º LAX07:53PMÂ PDT miÃ©2 horas 29 minutosAmerican Airlines AAL69 B763 Aterrizado miÃ©Â 11:00AMÂ CESTMAD â–º MIAMiami, FL AAL231 B752 Programado MIA â–º LAX08:35PMÂ PDT miÃ©3 horas 30 minutosAmerican Airlines AAL69 B763 Aterrizado miÃ©Â 11:00AMÂ CESTMAD â–º MIAMiami, FL AAL281 B763 Programado MIA â–º LAX06:10PMÂ PDT miÃ©1 hora Delta DAL109 B764 Aterrizado miÃ©Â 11:00AMÂ CESTMAD â–º ATLAtlanta, GA DAL2055 B763 Programado ATL â–º LAX06:32PMÂ PDT miÃ©1 hora 45 minutosBritish Airways BAW457 B763 Aterrizado miÃ©Â 10:45AMÂ CESTMAD â–º LHRLondon, EnglandAmerican Airlines AAL137 B77W En Vuelo / A Tiempo LHR â–º LAX05:15PMÂ PDT miÃ©1 hora 50 minutosDelta DAL127 B764 Aterrizado miÃ©Â 10:25AMÂ CESTMAD â–º JFKNew York, NY DAL424 B763 Programado JFK â–º LAX06:53PMÂ PDT miÃ©2 horas 42 minutosAmerican Airlines AAL95 B752 Aterrizado miÃ©Â 10:25AMÂ CESTMAD â–º JFKNew York, NY AAL117 B762 En Vuelo / A Tiempo JFK â–º LAX04:50PMÂ PDT miÃ©55 minutosAmerican Airlines AAL95 B752 Aterrizado miÃ©Â 10:25AMÂ CESTMAD â–º JFKNew York, NY AAL133 B762 Carreteando / SaliÃ³ de la puerta de embarque JFK â–º LAX06:40PMÂ PDT miÃ©2 horas 35 minutosAmerican Airlines AAL95 B752 Aterrizado miÃ©Â 10:25AMÂ CESTMAD â–º JFKNew York, NY AAL181 B762 Programado JFK â–º LAX07:40PMÂ PDT miÃ©3 horas 40 minutosAir France AFR1001 A319 Aterrizado miÃ©Â 10:10AMÂ CESTMAD â–º CDGParis AFR72 B772 En Vuelo / A Tiempo CDG â–º LAX04:05PMÂ PDT miÃ©1 hora 20 minutos
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS not works because you are getting only the text, maybe if you get the css and include it on your page it works

Comment: But I don't get the divs inside the div I want. So, I can't add the css. But If I get the all page all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the childnodes. Try XPath or parse the table inside of your div and get all the tr or td elements. So you can get all values and display them in a complete new style you want.
http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

Example:

```
$xp = new DomXPath($doc);
$trElements = $xp->query("*/table[@id='Results']/tbody/tr");

$data = array();
foreach ($trElements as $element) {
    // process your data here while grabbing all tr childnodes
}
```